# Error in MongoDB when using C# driver to deserialize a nested class

Tags: c#, mongodb, exception, deserialization, mongodb-.net-driver

Usually when I store an object into my collection and add a new property to my object, the mongodb C# driver will use a default value when the property isn't found in MongoDB. However, when I have a nested class, the official MongoDB C# driver doesn't seem to handle it the same way. See sample code:

```
MongoCollection<Person> peopleCollection = fd.GetCollection<Person>("peopledb");
Person p = peopleCollection.FindOne(); //errors here w/ Type Cast Exception
```

Happens when I add a new member to a nested class:

```
class Address {
    string street;
    string zip;
    string state; //newly added member, causing deserialization errors/cast exceptions
}

class Person {
    ObjectId _id;
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    Address personAddress;
}
```

In this case, when I do a FindOneAs, it will error out because Person.personAddress.state doesn't exist.

Does anybody know how I can make the deserializer also deserialize nested classes the same way?

Answer (score 0):

The c# driver deserialize automatically the nested classes if you pass specific type to find one kindly test the below example with mongo db

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
         //   MongoDatabase databse = MongoDatabase.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017/BeniSoftLabs");
            MongoDatabase mongodb = DBConn.DBConn.getDBConn();
            var menu = mongodb.GetCollection<Menu>("Menu").FindOne();


   }

 public class Node
    {
        public virtual string NodeTitle { get; set; }
        public virtual string Link { get; set; }
        public virtual string IconName { get; set; }
        public virtual string ClassName { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Node> NodeList { get; set; }

    }

 public class Menu
    {
        public virtual ObjectId id { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Node> MenuList { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Node> RightMenuList { get; set; }
    }
```

and the data model is

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("50fecb7d60df893ad0e25138"),
        "MenuList" : [
                {
                        "NodeTitle" : "About Us",
                        "Link" : "/href.html",
                        "IconName" : "icon-home",
                        "ClassName" : "active",
                        "NodeList" : null
                },
                {
                        "NodeTitle" : "Our Solution",
                        "Link" : null,
                        "IconName" : "icon-briefcase",
                        "ClassName" : "dropdown",
                        "NodeList" : [
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "HTML5 Apps",
                                        "Link" : "#/HTML5Apps",
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "CSS3 Apps",
                                        "Link" : "#/CSS3Apps",
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "Single Page Apps",
                                        "Link" : "#/SPAApps",
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "Smart Phone Apps",
                                        "Link" : "#/SMartPhoneApps",
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : ".Net Enterprise Apps",
                                        "Link" : "#/NETEnterprise",
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "Node.js Enterprise Apps",

                                        "Link" : "#/NodeEnterprise",
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "NodeTitle" : "Technologies",
                        "Link" : null,
                        "IconName" : "icon-briefcase",
                        "ClassName" : "dropdown",
                        "NodeList" : [
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "HTML5 & CSS3",
                                        "Link" : null,
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "Angular.js",
                                        "Link" : null,
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "Node.js",
                                        "Link" : null,
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "Asp.net MVC",
                                        "Link" : null,
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "MongoDB",
                                        "Link" : null,
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "NodeTitle" : "My Sql",
                                        "Link" : null,
                                        "IconName" : null,
                                        "ClassName" : null,
                                        "NodeList" : null
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "NodeTitle" : "Why Us",
                        "Link" : null,
                        "IconName" : "icon-fire",
                        "ClassName" : null,
                        "NodeList" : null
                }
        ],
        "RightMenuList" : [
                {
                        "NodeTitle" : "Join Us",
                        "Link" : null,
                        "IconName" : "icon-eye-open",
                        "ClassName" : null,
                        "NodeList" : null
                },
                {
                        "NodeTitle" : "Contact Us",
                        "Link" : null,
                        "IconName" : "icon-user",
                        "ClassName" : null,
                        "NodeList" : null
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: OK, now try to add a new property to your Node class, like a new string property. When I do so, a deserialization error is thrown.